# mapping a new array of objects results in undefined

Tags: lightning-web-components, object, array

I'm using this method:

```
processPromotions(){
    let promotionWithItem;
    this.allPromotions = this.sellerPromotions.map(promotion =>{
         promotionWithItem = this.findPromotion(promotion, false);
        if(promotionWithItem != undefined){
            promotion.item_in_promotion = true;
            promotion.item_regular_price = promotionWithItem.regular_price;
            promotion.item_deal_price = promotionWithItem.deal_price;
        }else{
            promotion.item_in_promotion = false;
        }
    })
    console.log(JSON.stringify(this.allPromotions[0]));
}
```

I'm mapping an existing array of objects to add new properties. Right now, I have one object in the original array, and when I checked the length of the new one, it says 1. but, when I log the object in the 0 index, it says undefined. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Except for the single line case of e.g.:

```
a => a + 100;
```

you do need to use `return` so adding:

```
return promotion;
```

at the end of your `=>` function would likely solve your problem.

(Though as you are mutating the `sellerPromotions` items the code might have unexpected side effects too.)

See e.g. [Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Comment: Thanks! I just talked to a coworker and he said exactly that, if I don't add a return, it wont do anything. and also, he said that it is not necessary to use the map function in this case, I can just assign the allPromotions array to the sellerPromotions and then use a for each to make the changes.

Comment: That wording is a bit weird. It's more accurate to say "if you use a code block `{}`, then a return statement is necessary". It's possible to use "more than one line" without a return statement.